# how to ignore multiple directories in nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I know how to ignore one directory in nodemon. but what is the way to ignore multiple directories at once in nodemon?

I tried this..but it didn't work for me..

```
  "nodemonConfig": {
       "ignore": ["directory_1","directory_2"] }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file,
To ignore the multiple directories you need to put them in the array as follows:

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": ["directory_1/*", "directory_2/*"]
}
```

You can check the details here in the [link](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#packagejson). Make sure the path should be correct of directories in the configuration.